# My hibernate mode is on stlll I cannot get the hibernate option

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I've tried almost everything from registry changes true pwrcfg -h on/off via hotfixes nothing returns the hibernate option in my start menu

Comment: silly question, but, do you have enough hard drive space free to go in to hibernation?

Comment: Update your graphics driver.

Comment: Shutdown /h works , I have enough disk space , I cannot edit my maximum memory (msconfig->startup->advanced...->maximum memory) I doesn't save my option after I press apply->OK